# Incremental build issue on Linux: is there alternative for default GCC linker?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

I'm using GCC to build my C++ application. There's one non-critical, but very annoying problem. My project contains many static libraries, and when I make changes in any of the libraries and build the project incrementally, the final executable does not reflect these changes. I must rebuild the whole project (or, more specifically, the library I've modified and the main executable it's linked to). I don't know if it's a Make bug or GCC's linker bug, but I wonder if a different linker would solve it. Seeing how there are several different linkers available for building Android libraries after compiling them with GCC, I wonder if there are alternate linkers for Linux.

P. S. There's exactly the same issue on Mac OS X (with Clang compiler).

Comment: This sounds like a bug in your makefile(s) rather than a bug in make or the linker.

Comment: @janneb: I'm using Qt, so the makefiles are generated automatically. What kind of a bug can it be? What should I look for in the makefile?

Comment: Well, make sure that the dependencies are correct. That is, after any of the library sources are changed the corresponding .o file is regenerated, and then the .a is recreated, and finally the main application relinked.

Comment: if you modify headers, you are changing the binary compatibility of the libraries. Maybe that is why you need to rebuild?

Comment: @BЈовић: 1. It doesn't matter if I change .h or .cpp file. 2. This problem is absent when building for Android (with GCC), not to mention Windows (MS compiler).

Comment: you can try the gold linker (google for "linux gold linker"), but I doubt it will resolve the issue

Comment: @BЈовић: yep, that didn't help.

Comment: Please verify manually if all necessary files are rebuild if you change a .h or .cpp file. If not, fix your Makefile by adding additional dependencies.